# Is Ruby's rand() good enough for gambling games?

Tags: ruby, random

I need to generate random results with the following properties:

- Uniform distribution (ie. numbers 1-10 are equally likely)
- Unpredictable (all results are public, and if datamined, should still not be able to predict the results)

The application deals with money, so it's critically important that the results stay unpredictable and are uniformally distributed.

Would regular pseudo-random generators fit this job or would you need a cryptographically strong rng? Would Ruby's default rand() work? Anything to watch out for?

If not, what solutions would you suggest?

EDIT:
Ruby 2.0.0 Random http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Random.html

Comment: If you are concerned, why not use the `Random` class instead of the default `rand`?

Comment: @sawa: Doesn't rand use Random class underneath? Is Random good enough? Looks like it uses the Mersenne Twister PRNG, and I'm not sure if that is good enough.

Comment: for true random, Use a microcontroller which can pick up on noise, see random.org

Comment: @randomguy No, it does not use it. I don't know if `Random` is enough, but is better than `rand`.

Comment: @user1281385: There are HTTP interfaces that use random.org's "truly" random generators, but I don't want to rely on an external service because of the HTTP overhead and the obvious trust issue.

Comment: This article will be helpful: http://www.sitepoint.com/tour-random-ruby/

Comment: @randomguy  was suggesting you setting up a microcontroller with the server, Would cost < $20

Comment: use a long wire in the ADC and read the LSB from there, That should be random enough (ie pass random tests) and fast enough

Comment: @user1281385: Cool idea, but impossible to incorporate into cloud hosting. :/

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's default rand uses Mersenne Twister algorithm. The internal state of the PRNG, although moderately large, and not *simple* to hack, is in theory small enough that just a few dozen values from 1 to 10 would be enough to determine its state, so your concerns are not unfounded. (Update: Evidently the internal state also "leaks" into the values returned, making hacking it even easier)

I would suggest you use [SecureRandom](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html), as it will typically use either `/dev/urandom` or the open-ssl library as a raw source of randomness. One of these is likely available on your target server, and no additional hardware or specialist libraries are required.

---

You may want to go further and look into modules that harvest entropy from an external source and then mix it using a cryptographic hashing algorithm (to get an even distribution of bit values). The Ruby gem [RealRand](http://realrand.rubyforge.org/) connects to some services which do this sort of thing. I could not find anything more modern in Ruby though.

If you are concerned with trusting third-party services, and have time to write your own Ruby wrapper, you could also take a look at a USB device [like this one](http://www.entropykey.co.uk/) that works from electronic noise.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer. Does cryptographically strong RNG automatically mean unpredictability and uniform distribution?

Comment: @randomguy: The algorithms are usually designed with an even distribution of bit values in mind, otherwise statistical analysis might help with an attack. However "unpredictability" of entropy sources is often seen in context of "what an attacker could know about the system" - in practice this is mostly the same thing, but might diverge for you or your customers in a philosophical sense.

Comment: @randomguy: Looking into this further, I think SecureRandom will serve you well enough in cloud hosting environments running Linux with `/dev/urandom` available (and/or open-ssl). Hence I have adjusted my answer to simply recommend you use SecureRandom in the first instance. As it will be a core part of your project, if you have time to look deeper into the subject it will serve you well.

Comment: Thanks! urandom pointed me to the right direction. Apparently, it uses the same entropy pool as /dev/random, but doesn't block when the pool is depleted as it re-uses old entropy via SHA1. It is still unclear to me whether this would compromise uniformality and unpredictability in a meaningful and practical (non-theoretical) way. The context is a normal Linux cloud-based VPS environment and gambling.

Comment: I wonder if pregenerating enough random numbers, or even entropy, with /dev/random is feasible and practical?

Comment: @randomguy: That may depend on how many you need. You have a different security issue then. Numbers are not predictable from each other, but would be very predictable to anyone with access to the pre-generated list. Also, depending on the game you are presenting online, it might be a philosophical break with how the game is perceived. Using it to build up a day's entropy pool might be a reasonable compromise. Although if you don't use the server for anything else, the pool will fill up, and get used by SecureRandom anyway when possible.